# The "GetItCmd" task failed unexpectedly - NullReferenceException

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I have a Delphi project in RAD Studio where I added a package using the GetIt Package Manager. After adding the package, I also added the package as a dependency to the project. But then the project does not build, and gives the following error:

```
[MSBuild Error] The "GetItCmd" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.CommandLineTask.Execute()
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.GetItCmd.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)
```

Using Google, I found this post on GitHub stating that I should set the `BCDHost` environment variable to "true".

https://gist.github.com/IgnoredAmbience/37ef8be48ffd58ee1c92d5b660ff6e3b

But why is that? What does this setting do?

Comment: BDSHost as in Borland Developer Studio Host.

Comment: It sets an environmental variable that has meaning to GetIt. It won't affect anything else on your system, because it only has meaning to the software that is looking for it. What it does internally can probably only be answered by someone working at EMBT with GetIt, and should probably be a question you ask EMBT support.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too (i.e. [MSBuild Error] The "GetItCmd" task failed unexpectedly.") when I had migrated from D 10.4 to D 11. It was enought to uncheck in compiller Options>Project Properties>GetIt Dependencies position: Unavailable 10.4 Community